# How to replace every occurance of multiple strings in a column with one unique new string in R

Tags: r, gsub, string-substitution

I have a column in a dataset which starts with `M, F or I`. I want to replace all the `M` or `F` in the column with `MF` and leave `I` untouched.

```
data$Sex:
"M"
"F"
"I"
"F"
"M"
"I"
```

I have tried the snippet as shown below, but to no avail.:

```
df <- data$Sex
for(i in names(df)){
  gsub("M","MF",df)
  gsub("F","MF",df)
}
```

I am new to R. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `gsub("M|F", "MF", df$Sex)`

Comment: Or probably `sub("[MF]", "MF", df$Sex)`. If you work with strings regularly, learning the basics of regular expressions will pay for itself by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

- the possible levels are currently "M", "F", and "I"
- `sex` is a `"factor"` column

define a mapping `levs` between old and new levels and then write this:

```
data <- data.frame(sex = c("M", "F", "I", "F", "M", "I")) # test input
```

Now try one of these:

```
levs <- c(F = "MF", M = "MF", I = "I") # mapping
transform(data, sex = factor(levs[sex])) ##

levels(data$sex) <- levs # levs defined above
```

If `sex` is a `"character"` column then the first one above still works if we remoive the word `factor` and this works as well:

```
data_c <- data.frame(sex = c("M", "F", "I", "F", "M", "I"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
transform(data_c, sex = replace(sex, sex %in% c("M", "F"), "MF"))
```

and the solution marked ## also works if the word `factor` is omitted.